# Augmented Reality App Store Process

Tags: iphone, app-store, augmented-reality

We have a client that has asked us to build an Augmented Reality iPhone App to be used at a show.
The experience will be location based, ie you will need to be at the show where the markers will be placed to use the app.

Does anyone know the process Apple take to test this kind of app? How will they be able to give approval if they cant test it without being on location and assess to the markers?

Is it possible to submit the markers to them as files to print out and test?!

Any info is MUCH appreciated as cant seam to find anything specific online.

Thank you,
Jason

Answer (score 1):

Put them online and give your reviewer links to each image.

I've done this before with QR Codes.

Comment: Ok, brilliant. Thank you. Will the reviewer then print them out and use them in situation?

Comment: It really depends on the reviewer.  I don't believe they will leave their computer station to test your app.  They will probably forge a location on the device and scan the image with their phone from their browser.  Be sure to include info on how to access your features and links to the images in the "Review Notes" section of your app submission.