# Points to note when applying augmented reality app

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm creating augmented reality app with Unity and vuforia.
this app platform is iOS and function is find AR marker then show character.
And now I'd like to applying to App Store.

I found a bit of notes about appliyng augmented reality application but I couldn't find more information in google.
Found informations is these.

~~~~~~

・The AR application has to specify that a marker is necessary in application as 
well as an explanation of appStore

・When I use the contents of the third party by application, it is necessary to submit that I get consent in the case of examination.

・
[Augmented Reality App Store Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476809/augmented-reality-app-store-process)
~~~~~~

If you know about any other notes of applying augmented reality application for App Store then please tell me about it.

thanks!

Comment: What is the question? Please make it a specific programming question.